# Selenium webdriver getting stuck and throws 'A coding exception was thrown and uncaught in a Task.'

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I have created a script with two tests, one for log in and another for navigating to another page through menu and performing a simple search using an application number. When I execute the script, the log in test works perfectly and the second test starts and navigates to the search page and then gets stuck and the following errors are thrown and the execution is stuck until I close the browser.

> " JavaScript error: http:///ui/login.jsf?visionStart=true, line
>   258: SyntaxError: missing ( before formal parameters
>
> JavaScript error: http:///ui/login.jsf, line 258: SyntaxError:
>   missing ( before formal parameters
>
> JavaScript error:
>   http:///ui/login.jsf?visionStart=true&auth=true, line 689:
>   SyntaxError: missing ( before formal parameters
>
> JavaScript error:
>   http:///javax.faces.resource/activex.js.jsf?ln=js/activex&1, line
>   164: SyntaxError: missing ( before formal parameters
>   ************************* A coding exception was thrown and uncaught in a Task.
>
> Full message: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch
>   resource. Full stack: "

I am unable to figure out, if my script is causing the problem or something else. Any help on this issue will be much appreciated. The URL from the above errors has been modified.

EDIT: Below is the code from test,

```
public void TC02_Verify_PermitSearchUsing_ApplicationID() throws InterruptedException {

    PermitSearch = new PermitSearchPage(driver);
    MainMenuList = new Menu_Master(driver);

    MainMenuList.Clickon_Main_Search_Menu();
    try {
        PermitSearch.Clickon_PermitSearch_Menu();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    PermitSearch.PermitSearchUsing_Appid("2147517");
```

As soon as the execution reaches the last line, those javascript errors start showing up. Below is the method that being called from the last line above,

```
public void PermitSearchUsing_Appid(String Application_ID) throws InterruptedException{

    wait  = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(AppID_text_box));

    driver.findElement(AppID_text_box).sendKeys(Application_ID);
    driver.findElement(SearchButton).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);

}
```

Comment: You'll need to add your code if you want people to give a proper answer

Comment: Please make sure that you are using the latest versions of FF, GeckoDriver and Selenium

Comment: Seems like the error is coming from your application rather than your testing code... DO you see these errors when you run this test manually?

Comment: @Grasshopper - That is what my feeling is too, but manually I was unable see those errors.

Comment: Have you checked in the Network tab of the console to check what is happening with requests and responses... Becoz at the end there is a network error.

Comment: @grasshopper - Yes I did. All the requests seem to be fine, I could see the status code as 200. One thing that I noticed that, most of the requests 
 get cached response and only few are not from cache. May be I'll try clearing the cache and run the tests.

Comment: @AnishPillai - I am using the latest versions of FF, geckodriver and selenium. I am thinking to may be downgrade FF and try.

Comment: @Qaddaffi - GeckoDriver v0.15.0 and Selenium 3.3.1 works well. If possible try with this combination